# Socket programming - write() fixed number of bytes from Java Servlet to server C

Tags: java, c, sockets, servlets

need some help reading the exact bytes from my java client side to C server. STREAM. I would like to read, lets say, the first two bytes then know which (string/Total No of bytes) are being sent thus use my recv_exactly() function which will take in the actual number of bytes as an argument. This is so that I can limit the wait time instead of reading all 1024 expected buffer size. AND also, any ideas how i can send a struct from the java side to make this neat.
Thanks a bunch!

```
          //***************  Java Client *****************

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        sslsocket.startHandshake();
    kmipoutstream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(kmipoutstream);

    // figure out what we want to ask for
    final String path = request.getPathInfo();

           System.out.println("request pathInfo: " + path);


    if (path == null || path.endsWith("/users")) {

           //***********SHOULD I SEND 13 FIRST = 2 BYTES?? ***************

                    outputstreamwriter.write("13")
        outputstreamwriter.write("GET ALL USERS");
    } else if (path.endsWith("/keys")) {
        outputstreamwriter.write("GET ALL KEYS");
    } else if (path.endsWith("/templates")) {
        outputstreamwriter.write("GET ALL TEMPLATES");}
    outputstreamwriter.flush();
    BufferedReader wireBufReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(sslsocket.getInputStream()));

    String tmp = wireBufReader.readLine();

    System.out.println(tmp);
    int numrows = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Cache-control", "max-age=0");
    response.setHeader("Content-Range", "0-" + numrows + "/" + numrows);

    while (!(tmp = wireBufReader.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
    response.getOutputStream().println(tmp);}
    kmipoutstream.close();
         }

           //**********  Server.C  *******************

           inBuf = calloc(1, 1024);
          if (inBuf == NULL){
      debug_print("ERROR: Memory allocation for inbuf.\n", NULL);
      endProcessing = 1;}
          printf("This is inBuf= %s \n", *inBuf);
             while (!endProcessing){
             sts = RS_SUCCESS;
             do{
            //do accept, followed by negotiate
            sts = rs_ssl_negotiate_viaAccept(rs_ssl_env, IOMODE_NONBLOCKING,
         listenerSocket, &rs_ssl_conn, &ssllog);
          printf("After negotiate and accept sts = %d\n", sts);

          if (RS_SUCCESS != sts){
    debug_print("ERROR: Error during accept and negotiate: %d\n", sts);
    rslog_print(ssllog);
    break;   
  /*
   * receive the get request, parse it out, and call the db method.
   */
  //memset(inBuf, 0, 1024);

   //*******I NEED HELP HERE. NOT SURE HOW TO KNOW THE EXACT NUMBER OF 
                     BYTES BEING SENT BEFORE I CALL
                                     RS_SSL_RECV_EXACTLY ********************

     if( = rs_ssl_recv_exactly(rs_ssl_conn, inBuf, 2, &ssllog)){
      debug_print("ERROR: During HTTP receive: %d\n", sts);
          rslog_print(ssllog);
          break; }
   else
   { if (sts = db_get_userlist_json(jInfo->db_ctx, &jsonBuf, &numrows))
              {debug_print("error getting json user: %d\n", sts);
                break;}}
  __atoe_l(inBuf, actualBytes);
 debug_print("successfully received %d bytes of request:\n<%s>\n", bytesRecvd, inBuf);

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
         sslsocket.startHandshake();
   kmipoutstream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
   OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(kmipoutstream);

   // figure out what we want to ask for
   final String path = request.getPathInfo();

   System.out.println("request pathInfo: " + path);

   if (path == null || path.endsWith("/users")) {

        // ******** SHOULD I SEND 13 FIRST = 2 BYTES??  ***********

      outputstreamwriter.write("13");
      outputstreamwriter.write("GET ALL USERS");
   } else if (path.endsWith("/keys")) {
      outputstreamwriter.write("GET ALL KEYS");
   } else if (path.endsWith("/templates")) {
      outputstreamwriter.write("GET ALL TEMPLATES");
   }
    outputstreamwriter.flush();
    BufferedReader wireBufReader = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(sslsocket.getInputStream()));

    String tmp = wireBufReader.readLine();

    System.out.println(tmp);
    int numrows = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Cache-control", "max-age=0");
    response.setHeader("Content-Range", "0-" + numrows + "/" + numrows);

    while (!(tmp = wireBufReader.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
        response.getOutputStream().println(tmp);
    }
    kmipoutstream.close();
}
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read as its indentation and use of white space is all over the place. Consider fixing this, so that we can understand it easier; if you do this you'll greatly increase your chances of getting good help. Specifically, indent each block 4 spaces (don't use tabs), avoid more than 1 empty line, and use your empty lines sparingly. Luck!

Comment: Not really, no you're not. I've manually fixed your first code block so that the indentations make sense. Please work on the others in the same vein.

Comment: Comment: `OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(kmipoutstream, StandardCbarsets.UT_8);` otherwise default server's encoding is taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is so that I can limit the wait time instead of reading all 1024 expected buffer size.

But recv() doesn't behave like that. It blocks until at least one byte is available (in blocking mode), then transfers whatever is available, up to the specified length. It makes no attempt to fill the buffer, unless that much data happens to be available.

So your problem doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: Good to know. By specified length you mean the exact number of bytes being sent? So EJP, i would like my recv() to use the exact byte length that's being sent. I have 3 if statements that write to my C server. Using recv() i'm not sure how to do this. do i call recv() twice?? I'm confused.

Comment: Well you would have to send the length on ahead, and then write a loop that receives until you get that length, incrementing the offset parameter and decrementing the length parameter as you go.